# How to use RegEx to add "_" between two words with notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to use Notepadd++ replace option with regular expression to accomplish this:

```
From: IntegrationName
To: Integration_Name
```

How can do this ?

My RegEx to search is: `.[A-Z]`
this finds: "oN"
But I don't know what to put in the replace box so it will only add "_" between the "o" and the "N"...

Comment: Show your attempt please. Also, is the period at the end of 'To:' part also being added or is this a typo?

Comment: In VI you can do it with this. Maybe it helps: `:%s/.\([A-Z]\)/_\1/` (/ separate what to replace with what).

Comment: I edited the question regarding your request

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) would be:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

and replace with

```
_
```

**Note**: The "Match case" option needs to be active, otherwise Notepad++ will find a match between every two letters.

This regex will find every position where a lowercase is on the left and an uppercase is on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of capture groups. If I have to take your current attempt and edit it as little as possible, you would get:

```
(.)([A-Z])
```

This will store the match of `.` into `$1` and the uppercase letter in `$2`, thus, you can use the following in the replace entry box:

```
$1_$2
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I know the principal of using "()" (-:

Comment: @LiranFridman Awesome :) You might want to explicitly state the character to be matched, like I would personally use `([a-z])([A-Z])` for the matching part, but since I don't know your context, I'll keep it like that and you can toy around and see what works better for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I know [you've accepted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26506529/3000179), but [when I ran it, I got `From: _Integration_Name`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iatMj.jpg)

Here's my idea;

```
(:\s)(.{1})([a-z]*)([A-Z]{1})
```

And use the following replace

```
$1$2$3_$4
```

[image]

Comment: Did you put the cursor at the start of the file and put the direction down?

Comment: Yes I did, but still not find

Answer (score 0):

I finaly did it like this:

```
Find: ([a-z])([A-Z])
Replace with: $1_$2
```